# help with .htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need some help regarding .htaccess rewrite rule.
One of my page have combination of following different values which need to be rewrite in different format.

```
http://mysite.com/test TO http://mysite.com/page.php
http://mysite.com/test/$cat/$id TO http://mysite.com/page.php?cat=$cat&id=$id
http://mysite.com/test/$cat TO http://mysite.com/page.php?cat=$cat
http://mysite.com/test/$cat/&next=13 TO http://mysite.com/page.php?cat=$cat&next=$next
```

I currently have following rule that only works for 2nd and 4th example

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.+)/(.+)/?$ page.php?cat=$1&id=$2
```

Comment: Is your to and from the wrong way around in the question?

Comment: Do you have the rewrites backwards? The rule you have rewrites `http://mysite.com/test/$cat/$id` TO `http://mysite.com/page.php?cat=$cat&id=$id`, not the other way around.

Comment: How do `$next` and `$id` differ? Will `$id` ALWAYS be numeric only, and will `$next` ALWAYS contain non-numeric character(s)?

Comment: @TheCodeKing I am not sure, but I corrected it.

Comment: @Joe value for `$next` should be passed in `&next=13` format at the end, actually I am using SmartyPaginate plugin and It doesn't let me change the link structure for `$next`, that's why I need to pass that value in default structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first 3 look pretty straightforward, but I don't understand what you mean by the fourth one, what exactly is `&next`? Is that a query string? Do you only care about this `&next` when it `=13`? Here's a stab at guessing what you're looking for (order matters):

```
# First
RewriteRule ^test$ page.php [L]
# Fourth ??
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)/([^=]+)=(.+)$ page.php?cat=$1&$2=$3 [L]
# Second
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)/([^=]+)$ page.php?cat=$1&id=$2 [L]
# Third
RewriteRule ^test/(.+)$ page.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

If the fourth one is supposed to be a query string, as in: `http://mysite.com/test/foo/?bar=13` then you need to change the last rule by adding a `QSA` to the end:

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.+)$ page.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If I'm misunderstanding still, we can include the rule you have

```
# First
RewriteRule ^test$ page.php [L]
# Third
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)$ page.php?cat=$1 [L] 
# Second and Fourth (your rule)
RewriteRule ^test/(.+)/(.+)/?$ page.php?cat=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

(you need the [L] at the end or else further rules get applied)

Comment: yes it's just a Query String and Thanks, your example just worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

These should work, creating separate rules for each case is a lot easier. I've had to make some assumptions on your URLs.

```
RewriteRule ^/test$ page.php
RewriteRule ^/test/([^/]+)/([^&/]+)$ page.php?cat=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^/test/([^/]+)$ page.php?cat=$1
RewriteRule ^/test/([^/]+)/&next=([^/]+)$ page.php?cat=$1&next=$2
```